# How to print out the indices of the answer?

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter

I was looking for the indices of the sum of two values is equal to the target number. The expected output of this program is {0,1}, but I got [I@1b6d3586 from the following code.

I know there might be something wrong with the method call, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {2, 7, 9, 11};
    System.out.println(twoSum(a, 9));

}

public static int[] twoSum(int[] arr, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == target) {
                return new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is a separate object and the mere text output of this object has nothing to do with its contents. You can use a StringBuilder or the Arrays.toString method instead.

**StringBuilder:**

```
int[] ints = new int[] {2, 3};

char separator = ' ';
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int anInt : ints) {
  builder.append(anInt).append(separator);
}
```

**Arrays.toString:**

```
int[] ints = new int[] {2, 3};

String arrayAsString = Arrays.toString(ints);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the result to a string. `int[]` can't be printed directly

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(a, 9)));
```